# How to send data from form to another page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to send "apparel clothing" size to another page but it's just giving me undefine

here is my product.js:

```
const [ pickSize, setPickSize ] = useState('');

<SelectSizesForm onSubmit={() => props.addBasket({ title, price, img_url1, pickSize })}>
    <SizeLabel>
        <SizeInput type="radio" name="pickSize" value="M" />
        <SizeSpan className="size">M</SizeSpan>
    </SizeLabel>
    <SizeLabel>
        <SizeInput type="radio" name="pickSize" value="L" />
        <SizeSpan className="size">L</SizeSpan>
    </SizeLabel>
    <SizeLabel>
        <SizeInput type="radio" name="pickSize" value="XL" />
        <SizeSpan className="size">XL</SizeSpan>
    </SizeLabel>
    <BuyButton type="submit">Add to Cart</BuyButton>
</SelectSizesForm>
```

How can I send `pickSize` in this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track changes on selection to change state value for pickSize like this:

```
const [ pickSize, setPickSize ] = useState('');

onChange = (value) = {
    setPickSize(value);
}

<SelectSizesForm onSubmit={() => props.addBasket({ title, price, img_url1, pickSize })}>
    <SizeLabel>
        <SizeInput onChange={() => onChange("M")} type="radio" name="pickSize" value="M" />
        <SizeSpan className="size">M</SizeSpan>
    </SizeLabel>
    
    ...
</SelectSizesForm>
```